# Batch - echo is off issue

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've checked other tons of answers related to my issue and none worked. I suppose it's a syntax typo, but I cannot seem to find it.

My script should simply tell me if a process is running, then save the path into a variable, go to that path and delete the `.exe`.

Unfortunately, I get `ECHO is OFF`. Any ideas why?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p PROGRAM=NAme of the exe:

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %PROGRAM%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%PROGRAM%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo. %PROGRAM% is running

for %%i in (%PROGRAM%) do (
    echo %%~$PATH:i
    set PROGRAM_PATH=%%~$PATH:i
)

cd %PROGRAM_PATH%

del /F %PROGRAM_PATH%

pause
```

Comment: **First piece of advice: Remove the `@echo off` line and run it again.**  That line is suppressing your best debug information.  Getting `ECHO is OFF` as output usually means you had an `echo` line with a blank after it, which means your problem is probably that `%%~$PATH:i` is evaluating to an empty string.  Are you sure `%PROGRAM%` is in the path?

Comment: `%PROGRAM_PATH%` is the entire path. `%PROGRAM%` is just the name of the `.exe`.

Comment: Did you get the text `yourProg.exe is running` or not? Did you enter `yourProg` or `yourProg.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I realized that my program wasn't doing what I wanted because the `.exe` didn't exist.

So, I modified a little bit the script, so that I will handle that case:

- if the `.exe` is running, exit because I won't be able to delete a already in use `.exe` anyway;
- otherwise go to its location and delete it.

**My final program:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
goto start_program

:start_program
    set /p PROGRAM=Name of exe(ex:cmd.exe):
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %PROGRAM%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%PROGRAM%">NUL

    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" do (
        goto enter_program
    )
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" do (
        goto exit_program
    )

:enter_program
    for %%i in (%PROGRAM%) do (
        set PROGRAM_PATH=%%~$PATH:i
    )
    cd %PROGRAM_PATH%
    del /f %PROGRAM_PATH%
    goto:eof

:exit_program
    goto:eof
```

Thanks for tips Ryan and jeb